# Strange errors in c (struct before variable declaration)

Tags: c, struct

Why in Xcode I have error in line:

```
my_type a;
```

there must be (according to Xcode):

```
struct my_type a;
```

But in TOR code I see what they do not use struct before variable declaration.

how does it work?

Comment: Either `my_type` is a `typedef` or you're compiling with a C++ compiler.

Comment: I believe C++ will also look in the namespace for struct tags when it can't find an identifier in the "regular" namespace. C needs to be told to look there.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so structs in C. You have two options.
You can do something like

```
struct a {
        ...
};

struct a a1;

//OR

typedef struct a {


} a;


a a1;
```

Comment: Why do you name it `atype` instead of just `a`? Nothing prevents you from giving the same name.

Comment: it's very cool, I don't know that, but in tor code there is not "typedef struct ..."
There is only "struct cell_t { };" but if they make variables they use "cell_t" without "struct"!

Comment: @Zyycyx How is it more understandable? If you think `atype` is more descriptive, then use `typedef struct atype { ... } atype`

Comment: @klutt Well, maybe you're right. Thank you for the suggestion.